# Cannot Connect API at Locahost from Android Mobile

Tags: android, mysql, api, localhost

I have an app with web admin panel which I installed on localhost (xammp). Android app is supposed to connect with the API at localhost to communicate.

**Note:**

**I'm using a Physical Android device to test run my application instead of using the emulator. That's why I'm trying to use IPv4 of host computer as Base URL.**

**android:usesClearTextTraffic="true" is already added in manifest file.**

What I tried:

- Got IP of host computer by ipconfig and use it in the Android Studio code as Base URL
- Used port 80 as well from xammp apache
- Using localhost opens the website in my computer browser
- Using IP of computer/host can access website/api from my mobile phone browser
- I have installed all setup on online server and domain name, when I use domain as the base_url it works fine and I can use the App. But app won't even let me login when using IP address of localhost.

This is the code of localhost IP base_url I'm currently using but it's not working.

```
    //For retrofit base url must end with /
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.xxx.xx/api/";

//For retrofit base url must end with /
public static final String PRODUCT_IMAGE_URL = "http://192.168.xxx.xx/poduct_images/";
```

Have spent 4 hours searching and tried many things but could not find any solution.

Looking for some guidance please.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you developing on an physical Android device or an emulator?

Comment: @SalvatoreTesta Yes I'm using a physical Android device to run my app that's why trying to use the IP address of host computer but it won't work.

Comment: Did you add android:usesClearTextTraffic="true" to application tag of manifest file?

Comment: @blackapps yes it's there already.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your computer from your Android emulator, you'll want to use the [Android loopback address](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses) `10.0.2.2` instead of where you'd normally think to use `127.0.0.1`.

If you want to use a physical device, I recommend setting up the reverse tethering tool, [gnirehtet](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet). With your phone plugged into your laptop, you can use your phone the same way you would an emulator. This would allow you to use `10.0.2.2` to access your laptop.

Comment: Sorry but I'm using a Physical Android device to run the app. That's why trying to use IPv4 address of host computer as Base URL but that never works for me.

Comment: Updated to include instructions for accessing your laptop with your physical Android device.

Comment: Hey @Taimoor, did this solve your issue?